# Perl6 log method returns a Num not a Rat

Tags: raku

Just wondering if anyone knows why Perl6's log function returns a Num type and not a Rat type.

```
say (e*e).log.WHAT;
> (Num)
say (2/3).WHAT;
> (Rat)
```

Comment: P6 isn't doing symbolic math in the above. `e` is an *irrational* number. `Num`s are double floats. `Rat`s are rational. I'm not sure this is useful info but it's short. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because no one has done the work to make it do anything else yet. It's a situation that the language could handle (not that it's special to Perl 6) but also a situation that you might not want it to handle.

There's no object that represents the natural base `e` and maintains it as such until it can't any longer (just as `Rat`s don't turn into `Num`s unless they have to). That's possible and would also allow us to decide how to treat it. Maybe we want a `Rat`, or `FatRat`, or even a certain number of decimal places in a `Num`. But it doesn't do that.

It's not that `e` is special though. It doesn't work with powers of 10 either:

```
> 100.log10
2
> 100.log10.^name
Num
```

The code behind `.log10` could check that the operand is a power of 10 and decide to return an `Int` in that case. But it would have to check every number for that and most numbers aren't a power of 10. Checking all of those would slow down the process. It's easier to make it a little "incorrect".

But you can use `.narrow` to get a more constrained type possibly:

```
> 100.log10.narrow.^name
Int
```

This is different from asking for a particular type and maybe getting a different number:

```
> (10/3).Int
3
> (10/3).narrow.^name
Rat
```

And for fun:

```
 > i*i
-1+0i
 > (i*i).^name
 Complex
 > (i*i).narrow.^name
 Int
```

Answer (score 6):

In mathematics Log is a Continuous function therefore it has mathematically-real values. `Num` type describes mathematically-real numbers in Perl 6. `Rat` type describes mathematically-rational numbers.

Comment: `Num` is a float. The `Real` role better represents mathematically-real values. `Int`, `Rat`, and `Num` all do the `Real` role. The `Numeric` role encapsulates all the types `Real` does, with the addition of `Complex` number types.

Answer (score 5):

Perl6 is not a computer algebra system, so it treats `e*e` like any other `Num` - and once you've got a floating point number, only explicit operations such as rounding should change the type to something like `Int` or `Rat`: The computer cannot know if the return value `2e0` of `(e*e).log` actually represents `2`, or some `2+ε`.